# spring-boot fails on multi-module app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I tried to create spring-boot application with multiple modules with structure as follows:

```
omnibus/
   /domain
   /persistence
   /service
   /web
```

In main pom I set spring-boot-starter-parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>omnibus</groupId>
<artifactId>omnibus</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>persistence</module>
    <module>domain</module>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>web</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>pl.omnibus.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

In web module I included class:

```
package pl.omnibus;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml of web module is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>omnibus</artifactId>
    <groupId>omnibus</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>web</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>omnibus</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now when I try to execute:

```
mvn package
```

on the project if fails on tests of persistence module because it doesn't see dependency for domain although it is declared in persistence pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>omnibus</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    (...)
</dependencies>
```

What's strange those commands pass with success:

```
mvn test
mvn package -DskipTests
```

But even in case of the latter I cannot run web.jar because

```
java -jar web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

fails on java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for class from domain module.
I would appreciate any help as I'm new to spring-boot and cannot find solution for creating spring-boot app with multiple modules.

EDIT:
I'm adding output of

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

for @chrylis

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] omnibus
[INFO] domain
[INFO] persistence
[INFO] service
[INFO] web
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building omnibus 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ omnibus ---
[INFO] omnibus:omnibus:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building domain 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ domain ---
[INFO] omnibus:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building persistence 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ persistence ---
[INFO] omnibus:persistence:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- omnibus:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jooq:jooq:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jooq:jooq-meta:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jooq:jooq-codegen:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1201-jdbc41:compile
[INFO] +- org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.11:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.11:test
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:test
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.11:test
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |           \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building service 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ service ---
[INFO] omnibus:service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- omnibus:persistence:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- omnibus:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jooq:jooq:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jooq:jooq-meta:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jooq:jooq-codegen:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1201-jdbc41:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building web 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ web ---
[INFO] omnibus:web:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- omnibus:service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- omnibus:persistence:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- omnibus:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jooq:jooq:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jooq:jooq-meta:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jooq:jooq-codegen:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1201-jdbc41:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] omnibus ............................................ SUCCESS [ 21.195 s]
[INFO] domain ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.121 s]
[INFO] persistence ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.840 s]
[INFO] service ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.193 s]
[INFO] web ................................................ SUCCESS [  0.304 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.970 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-16T17:25:06+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Boot and is entirely a Maven issue. Post the output of `dependency:tree` from your top-level directory.

Comment: `java -jar web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ` won't work out the box unless you have used a maven plugin to re-package all of your dependencies or have generated a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF with the paths to all of the dependencies. Sorry, I don't have an example at hand to share, but you can [read the docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html)

Comment: @Augusto I thought it was possible when using spring-boot-maven-plugin according to this [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html)

Comment: Yes, spring-boot-maven-plugin has a goal to take care of it. No need to add anything else. See my answer below for a suggested fix.

Comment: What about spring-boot:run? I used this to run single spring boot web app. Then I add there new parent pom and another module. And after that I have the same problem as you - failure to find dependency. I want to exec spring-boot:run, but where? At parent pom? At web-app module? Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

Your command output seems weird as you mentioned the groupId is "app" in the question, however the command output shows the groupId is "omnibus" and not app.

Try changing the dependency to:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>omnibus</groupId>
    <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
(...)
```

The same goes for all other module dependencies.

Comment: It's my mistake - I changed the name from app to omnibus in the meantime. Now I edited the first post to reflect current state of application but still the same error occurs. No idea what I'm doing wrong. Package goal still doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like the module order is incorrect in your main pom. If persistence depends on domain it should appear below it.

Comment: @Koby are you sure, that order in module statement in parent pom is important? I have the same problem as described in question, but changing the order doesn't change anything.

Comment: As far as I remember the order in the parent is important. What error are you getting? The NoClassDefFoundError? Can you post the output of your maven command?

Comment: @Koby I try to call spring-boot:run on web submodule, but I see only: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project superproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.pro:superproject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.pro:shared-libs:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: I'm assuming shared-libs is part of your modules, am I right? If so, did you try to run `mvn clean install` from the root pom (where all modules are defined) before running `mvn spring-boot:run`?

Comment: @Koby Thank you very much. This helps: when I run `mvn install` it installs needed modules in local maven repository, so when I call `spring-boot:run`, it knows where is my jars. It is not ideal solution, because I think, that `spring-boot:run` could get dependency from parent pom. But since `mvn install` works it is ok. Thanks.

Comment: Since it is the solution @koby's comment should be rewritten as an answer and accepted by jososnowski